# bootstrap floating labels slides to the center when the direction is rtl

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, direction

I am trying to display floating labels in Hebrew using bootstrap v5.2.
The problem is that when I change the direction to rtl when the input box is clicked the label slides towards the middle.

my code:

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3" dir="rtl">
        <input class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="כותרת"></input>
        <label for="title">כותרת</label>
</div>
```

[You can see that the text moves to the center and does not stay adjacent to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqyg0.png)

I tried to change the direction back to ltr only in the label, it worked but it doesn't look good in Hebrew (sticks to the left side of the box).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a custom class and use these css codes:

```
<style>
    .form-floating.custom-class>label {
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        transform-origin: 100% 0;
        transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out,transform .1s ease-in-out;
    }
    .form-floating.custom-class>.form-control-plaintext~label, .form-floating.custom-class>.form-control:focus~label, .form-floating>.form-control:not(:placeholder-shown)~label, .form-floating>.form-select~label {
        opacity: .65;
        transform: scale(.85) translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(-0.15rem);
    }
</style>


<div class="form-floating mb-3 custom-class" dir="rtl">
    <input class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="כותרת"></input>
    <label for="title">כותרת</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Magic. I used ltr on the input itself for numbers and stuff and it works like a charm.